# How to create objects before class?

Tags: c++, declaration

I know that we cannot user a variable or an object before declaring in.

Below three classes are there and in order to use these class I made three objects(before class) and i thought if I will write class name; it would work but its giving error!

I have searched related to this on stack but I was not clarified.

**Why i am getting error & how to remove it ?**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bit;    
class Nibble; 
class Byte;   

Bit bito;   //Object for Bit
Nibble no;  //Object for Nibble
Byte byteo; //Object for Byte

class Bit
{
    public:

    static int count;
    static int bit[100000];

    void add()
    {
        bit[count++]=2;
    }
    void check()
    {
        int k=0;
        if(count)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                if(--bit[i]==0)
                {
                    no.add();
                    k++;
                }

            }
            int n=k;
            int i=0;
            while(n-->0)
            {
                bit[i]=bit[i+1];
                i++;
            }
            count-=k;
        }
    }


};

int Bit::count=0;
int Bit::bit[100000]={0};
bito.add();

class Nibble
{
    public:

    static int count;
    static int nibble[100000];

    void add()
    {
        nibble[count++]=8;
    }
    void check()
    {
        int k=0;
        if(count)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                if(--nibble[i]==0)
                {
                    byteo.add();
                    k++;
                }

            }
            int n=k;
            int i=0;
            while(n-->0)
            {
                nibble[i]=nibble[i+1];
                i++;
            }
            count-=k;
        }
    }


};

int Nibble::nibble[100000]={0};
int Nibble::count=0;

class Byte
{
    public:

    static int count;
    static int byte[100000];

    void add()
    {
        byte[count++]=16;
    }
    void check()
    {
        int k=0;
        if(count)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                if(--byte[i]==0)
                {
                    bito.add();
                    bito.add();
                    k++;

                }

            }
            int n=k;
            int i=0;
            while(n-->0)
            {
                byte[i]=byte[i+1];
                i++;
            }
            count-=k;
        }
    }


};

int Byte::count=0;
int Byte::byte[100000]={0};
```

Comment: No regrets & no other way so I used helper functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't -- declaring a `forward declaration` (as you are doing) only lets the compiler know that a class with the name you specified exists; it doesn't tell the compiler anything about the class (such as its size), and therefore the compiler can't instantiate objects of that type until after it has parsed in their classes' class-declarations.  So you'll need to declare your three objects *after* their class's declarations.

Comment: what do you mean by parsed ?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Friesner now I have realized the bug.